# How do you get github access token for repo or other permissions with Auth0?

Tags: vue.js, jwt, github-api, auth0

I have built a SPA with Vue and for the authentication I am using Auth0. I have just enabled the github signon connection and it is working as expected, since I have set it to have permissions to access the repos of the user it is asks for that permission during the signup process. But, now I don't know how to get the github acess token to actually get the lists of repos or do anything else. The documentation has been a little sparse so looking for some help.
I use the "@auth0/auth0-vue" library with a fast api backend. I followed the tutorial/template from auth0 and the login and signup work fine. How do I now get the github access token to gain access? after I do I know I just call the "https://api.github.com/users/{username"/repos" endpoint to get the repo details but if I use the auth0 access token it returns unauthorized.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like I have to call this enedpoints https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token/
When you use authticate using auth0 it will call your callback url with a code param. You will need to use this to make an axios call you can use to get the token, also I am currently getting a cors error. I don't plan to use this in my client end when after this so that will most likely not be an issue:

```
export const getGithubRepos = async (path, accessToken, email) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('client_id', 'github_client_id');
  params.append('client_secret', 'github_secret');
  params.append('code', 'code_form_callback_url');

  axios.post('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token/', params, {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log('Access Token:', response.data.access_token);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error during token exchange:', error);
  });
};
```